# Freeradius acct_unique module package not available on OpenWrt CC-15.05.1

Tags: embedded, cross-compiling, openwrt, freeradius, linksys

I'm running Openwrt CHAOS CALMER (15.05.1, r48532) on my linksys WRT1900AC V1 (mamba - mvebu platform).

I have installed freeradius server version 2.2.8, i'm facing troubles with the acct unique session id which is all the time empty:

```
rlm_sql_mysql: MYSQL check_error: 1062 received
[sql] Couldn't insert SQL accounting STOP record - Duplicate entry '' for 
key 'acctuniqueid'
rlm_sql_mysql: MYSQL check_error: 1062 received
rlm_sql_mysql: Cannot store result
rlm_sql_mysql: MySQL error 'Duplicate entry '' for key 'acctuniqueid''
rlm_sql (sql): Released sql socket id: 9
++[sql] = fail
+} # group accounting = fail
Finished request 21.
Cleaning up request 21 ID 5 with timestamp +1271
Going to the next request
Ready to process requests.
```

Reading the freeradius mailing list it seems that the only solution is to use the "acct_unique" module which is not available for download using the opkg install tool from OpenWrt console.
I beg any one who have this package (ipk already compiled for the mvebu platform) or he have the OpenWrt build system and he can cross compile this module to help me sort my issue by helping me to get this module for my platform.

Any other alternative solutions to sort out this problem using shell scripting call from the freeradius daemon are welcome.

Here is the list of packages available for freeradius :

`root@OpenWrt:~# opkg find '*freeradius*'
freeradius2 - 2.2.8-2 - A flexible RADIUS server (version 2)
freeradius2-common - 2.2.8-2 - common files
freeradius2-democerts - 2.2.8-2 - Demo certificates to test the server
freeradius2-mod-always - 2.2.8-2 - Always module
freeradius2-mod-attr-filter - 2.2.8-2 - ATTR filter module
freeradius2-mod-attr-rewrite - 2.2.8-2 - ATTR rewrite module
freeradius2-mod-chap - 2.2.8-2 - CHAP module
freeradius2-mod-detail - 2.2.8-2 - Detailed accounting module
freeradius2-mod-eap - 2.2.8-2 - Base EAP module
freeradius2-mod-eap-gtc - 2.2.8-2 - EAP/GTC module
freeradius2-mod-eap-md5 - 2.2.8-2 - EAP/MD5 module
freeradius2-mod-eap-mschapv2 - 2.2.8-2 - EAP/MS-CHAPv2 module
freeradius2-mod-eap-peap - 2.2.8-2 - EAP/PEAP module
freeradius2-mod-eap-tls - 2.2.8-2 - EAP/TLS module
freeradius2-mod-eap-ttls - 2.2.8-2 - EAP/TTLS module
freeradius2-mod-exec - 2.2.8-2 - EXEC module
freeradius2-mod-expiration - 2.2.8-2 - Expiration module
freeradius2-mod-expr - 2.2.8-2 - EXPR module
freeradius2-mod-files - 2.2.8-2 - Module using local files for authorization
freeradius2-mod-ldap - 2.2.8-2 - LDAP module
freeradius2-mod-logintime - 2.2.8-2 - Logintime module
freeradius2-mod-mschap - 2.2.8-2 - MS-CHAP and MS-CHAPv2 module
freeradius2-mod-pap - 2.2.8-2 - PAP module
freeradius2-mod-passwd - 2.2.8-2 - Rlm passwd module
freeradius2-mod-preprocess - 2.2.8-2 - Request pre-processing module
freeradius2-mod-radutmp - 2.2.8-2 - Radius UTMP module
freeradius2-mod-realm - 2.2.8-2 - Realms handling module
freeradius2-mod-sql - 2.2.8-2 - Base SQL module
freeradius2-mod-sql-mysql - 2.2.8-2 - MySQL module
freeradius2-mod-sql-pgsql - 2.2.8-2 - PostgreSQL module
freeradius2-mod-sql-sqlite - 2.2.8-2 - SQLite module
freeradius2-mod-sqlcounter - 2.2.8-2 - Generic SQL Counter module
freeradius2-mod-sqllog - 2.2.8-2 - SQL Logging module
freeradius2-utils - 2.2.8-2 - Misc. client utilities`

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `raddb/policy.conf`

Add

```
acct_unique {
    update request {
            Acct-Unique-Session-Id := "%{md5:%{User-Name},%{Acct-Session-ID},%{NAS-IP-Address},%{NAS-Identifier},%{NAS-Port-ID},%{NAS-Port}}"
    }
}
```

You can then add a call to `acct_unique` in `raddb/sites-available/default` at the top of the `preacct {}` section, to generate the `Acct-Unique-Session-ID` attribute.

Comment: Hi @Arran, I followed your hints, but now it complains about the md5 module. Here is the FR console log : `# Executing section preacct from file /etc/freeradius2/sites/default
+group preacct {
++policy acct_unique {
+++update request {
WARNING: Unknown module "md5" in string expansion "%"
+++} # update request = noop
++} # policy acct_unique = noop
+} # group preacct = noop`. It seems also that this module is unvailable.  kind regards

Comment: Hi @Arran [link](http://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-devel/2013-July/008329.html). In this link i found the remaining piece to make every thing working. Amazing job sir. Thank you so much for your precious help.